# Browser Helper Object UI

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, plugins, user-interface, bho

I am a newbie working towards developing an IE extension that would appear as an overlay in certain webpages. I am getting started by creating a simple BHO in VS2008 (using C++), but I am wondering how UI may be incorporated within the project. Any ideas?
Just to give you an idea, I'm looking for overlays similar to what was developed by stickis
http://www.stickis.com/faq/

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using CreateWIndowEx() was what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

You have two real options:

1> Inject your UI into the page as HTML.
2> Overlay your UI (using Windows graphics APIs) over top of the page.

Neither of these is super-simple, I'm afraid.  Unfortunately, doing UI is usually the hardest part of building IE addons.

The key question is whether you need a BHO at all.  Between context-menu extensions and IE8 Accelerators, you may find that you can let IE do all of the heavy lifting.  See www.enhanceie.com/ie/dev.asp for more info.

Comment: Thanks Eric,
I have explored context-menu extensions and IE8 accelerators as well, but I guess I didn't go deep enough to be able to create user interfaces. Could you guide me as to how I should proceed? I checked the link you provided, but it didn't seem to answer the question I have in mind.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: When you create a context menu extension, you can show a HTML-based UI in response to activation of the extension, or you can inject markup into the current document to show your UI.  

You can look at the raw source of the IEToys samples (available from www.enhanceie.com/ietoys) to see how these approaches work.

For accelerators, the "preview" experience loads a HTML UI, and when the user invokes the activity, it navigates to the HTML page.